# A collision triggers an animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my player hit an object, destroying the object and triggering an animation, but everything I try causes an error. I am relatively new at c# so the answer may be obvious but I need help. How can I set it up so that the collision will cause the object to disappear and the player to play an animation? Here is the script I am currently trying.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class succ : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = .15f;
    public static float jumpSpeed = 170f;
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<ConstantForce2D>().enabled = false;
        GameObject.Find("goal");
    }

    public bool animation_bool;
    private object coll;
    private object other;

    void Update()
    {
        OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll);
        {
            if (coll.gameObject.tag == "succ") ;
            {
                animation_bool = true;
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("succ", animation_bool);
                GetComponent<ConstantForce2D>().enabled = true;
                Destroy(other.object);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Destroy(object gameObject)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision2D, object coll)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: After seeing the `OnCollisionStay2D` callback function inside the `Update` function, I suggest you learn C# first. There are many online tutorials out there. This will save you time and at the-same time, save other people's time that will read your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I can see that are wrong, but I'll start by answering your question.

I suggest you change your MonoBehaviour method OnCollisionStay2D to OnCollisionEnter2D. [OnCollisionStay2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html) is "sent each frame where a collider on another object is touching this object's collider". [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is "sent when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's collider".

I believe you are looking for the latter since you only want to trigger this once during the collision. You are also destroying the other object, making it impossible to call OnCollisionStay2D anymore even if you wanted to do so.

You should also remove your Update method. I honestly do not understand what you are trying to achieve there now. All of the OnCollision methods get called automatically; you do not have to call them yourself.

Then you can use the Awake and OnCollisionEnter2D methods as follows

```
public class Succ : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // You can already get a reference to the Animator on Awake
        // This way you do not have to do it on every collision
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Use OnCollisionEnter2D instead since the code
    // needs to be excecuted only once during the collision
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("succ")
        {
            // Assuming that you only want to trigger an animation once
            // to reflect attacking or colliding, you could use SetTrigger
            // instead. Otherwise you need to use SetBool again to set it
            // back to false. You should then change the Animator parameter 
            // accordingly, from a bool to a trigger.
            animator.SetTrigger("succ");
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }  
    }
}
```

Apart from this, I have a few things I would like to comment on:

- I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by setting your ConstantForce2D component to false on Start and then setting it to true on collision.
- You seem to be using GameObject.Find on Start. GameObject.Find is something that should be very rarely used. It can be extremely expensive, especially if your Scene has a lot of GameObjects in it; this is because it simply goes through the Hiearchy, comparing the parameter string to names of GameObjects until it either finds a match or runs out of GameObjects.
- Moreover, you are using GameObject.Find on Start to look for a GameObject, but then you do not store that anywhere, making the whole finding process completely pointless.

Overall, I recommend you to take a look at all of the different learning resources offered by Unity themselves. Your question is about fairly basic functionality that is certainly covered during all of the different tutorials.